# Replacing AJAX with cURL in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, curl, http-headers

i have some simple situation, but for me, it looks like very tough at the moment.

I am trying to scrap a web, which uses AJAX calls to fetch data.

> http://www.economia-nmx.gob.mx/normasmx/index.nmx

has a form, after checking appropriate options, and pressing `submit` button. an ajax call is send and in response, data is printed on the page. there is NO JSON involved in this.

Using firebug and web developer tools, I am able to see referral URL, params, and cookie and other stuff involved, request header in Firebug looks like

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=cYJtPcYGYs2dM12QXgD3vGfnnQFVX3cTzfFbYLwWBkmXv4m47jh1!924382716
Host    www.economia-nmx.gob.mx
Referer http://www.economia-nmx.gob.mx/normasmx/index.nmx
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
consultasvarias.nmx http://www.economia-nmx.gob.mx/normasmx/consulta.nmx
```

can somebody please tell me, how can I CURL the page (in php)?

what data I MUST send in CURl?

OR i have to generate full request header?

what are the CURL options I must set for this?

Guide me please and thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just try to mimic the ajaxrequest.

The parameters you can mimic with:

```
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'id'=>'Bar'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

You could start out by checking the [phpmanual on curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)

Comment: can you explain "mimic" please in some simple words please?

Comment: With mimic I meant you include the same parameters in your request as the ajaxrequest does.